# how do you update multiple NamedRanges via C# GoogleSheets API?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm able to update a single NamedRange using Update(), and multiple GridCoordinate ranges using BatchUpdate, but I can't work out how to update NamedRanges in a BatchUpdate. How is this done?

The single NamedRange update I can do like this:

```
        ValueRange vr = new ValueRange();
        vr.Range = "aRange";
        var l1 = new List<object>();
        l1.Add("Here");
        IList<IList<object>> l2 = new List<IList<object>>();
        l2.Add(l1);
        vr.Values = l2;
        var rqe2 = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(vr, spreadsheetId, "aRange");
        rqe2.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
        rqe2.Execute();
```

and a GridCoordinate via BatchUpdate I can do like this:

```
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest busr = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        busr.Requests = new List<Request>();
        Request r = new Request();
        busr.Requests.Add(r);
        r.UpdateCells = new UpdateCellsRequest();

        var gc = new GridCoordinate();
        gc.ColumnIndex = 0;
        gc.RowIndex = 5;
        gc.SheetId = 0;

        r.UpdateCells.Start = gc;
        r.UpdateCells.Fields = "*";
        r.UpdateCells.Rows = new List<RowData>();

        var rd = new RowData();
        r.UpdateCells.Rows.Add(rd);
        rd.Values = new List<CellData>();
        var cd = new CellData();
        cd.UserEnteredValue = new ExtendedValue();
        cd.UserEnteredValue.StringValue = "UserEnteredValue";
        rd.Values.Add(cd);

        SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest bur = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(busr, spreadsheetId);
        bur.Execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using two different kinds of updates above, [values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) & [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).

The `values` API collection works with A1 ranges, which include named ranges, sheet names, row numbers (1-based) and column letters.  The `spreadsheets` API collection works with `GridRange`, `GridCoordinate`, `DimensionRange`, etc.. objects, all of which work with sheet IDs and row/column indexes (0-based).

If you'd like to do a batch update of values within named ranges, you want to use the [values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) API, not the `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` API.

The API in C# should be a fairly straightforward mapping of the info on the reference docs, probably using `SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchUpdateRequest`.

Comment: worked well. One further trick was that I had to set the ValueInputOption like this:
            var buvr = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
            buvr.ValueInputOption = ((int)SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED).ToString();